# Is an (auto-)shrink of a combobox after repopulation really impossible?

Tags: combobox, gtk

I'm referring to the comment by underscore_d given in the context of this question [Gtk ComboBox width based on contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11975230/gtk-combobox-width-based-on-contents):

> If you [...] change [the model of a combobox to a new one] with all shorter options... [the combobox] doesn't
>   shrink back down.

I've noticed that myself, and I've tried to shrink the combobox with

```
gtk_widget_queue_draw (combobox);
while (gtk_events_pending ()) {
   gtk_main_iteration ();
}
```

but to no avail; other "tricks" like using `gdk_threads_add_idle` didn't work either.

So there is no way, either by code or by any setting, to shrink an overly wide combobox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I destroy now the combo box widget and recreate it every time; the size change is quite big and the combo box looks really bulky if I don't do this. Not very elegant, but so be it.